# How to sort an array of tuples by an Int value?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift3, tuples, xcode8

I have an array of tuples (

```
 var array = [("John Doe", 13), ("The Guy", 15), ("The Person", 19)]
```

and want to sort them by the int value going from greatest to least. At the end I want the array to look like this

```
 var array = [("The Person", 19), ("The Guy", 15), ("John Doe", 13)]
```

How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
   var array = [("John Doe", 13), ("The Guy", 15), ("The Person", 19)]

    print("myStringArray: \(array)\n")
    array.sort {$0.1 > $1.1}
    print("myStringArray: \(array)\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

You must compare, by the `$1` value that is the Int value of the tuple, check this code, will help you

```
        var tuplesArray : [(String,Int)] = [("John Doe", 13), ("The Guy", 15), ("The Person", 19)]
        let orderedTuples = tuplesArray.sorted { (value1, value2) -> Bool in
                return value1.1 > value2.1
        }
```

I hope this helps you

Comment: A statement like `if someCondition { return true } else { return false }` can always be simplified to `return someCondition`.

Comment: Thanks @MartinR for your recommendation, my answer was edited